# Не понимаю как авторизироваться в google form с помощью Python Request

Tags: python, requests, google-forms

Я написал парсер для заполнения любой гугл формы. Но столкнулся с проблемой, что если в настройках выставить эти параметры:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То при отправке POST запроса надо как-то авторизировать свой google аккаунт.
Перерыл кучу инфы и везде используют googleApi в связке с GoogleConsole

Но в GoogleConsole используют OAth2.0 для авторизации СВОИХ форм. А мне нужно авторизироваться в чужих.

Помогите пожалуйста!

Форма которую я пытаюсь парсить: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdFzhdjSIoD2m7hrw6dyAiUqG-viyj0ORXn9M1yLpReiRXT7A/viewform?usp=sf_link

Мой текущий код:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://forms.gle/fBg2Xnjv8rtnvwYYA"

page = requests.get(url)
api = page.url.split('/')[len(page.url.split('/'))-2]
responseUrl = f"https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/{api}/formResponse?"

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

allButtons = soup.findAll('div', role='button')
index = 1
email = input('Email: ')

#Если на странице есть кнопка "Далее"
while "Далее" in list(button.text for button in allButtons):
    tmpResponseUrl = f"https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/{api}/formResponse?emailAddress={email}&"
    allNews = soup.select('[data-params]')
    for i in allNews:
        text = i['data-params']
        number = text[text.find('[',7)+2: text.find(',', text.find('[',7))]
        print(i.text)
        inputs = input(f"{number}|Вопрос №{index} ")

        index += 1
        responseUrl += "entry." + number + f"={inputs}&"
        tmpResponseUrl += "entry." + number + f"={inputs}&"

    pageHistory = soup.find('input', {'name': 'pageHistory'})
    tmpResponseUrl += f"pageHistory={str(pageHistory['value'])}&"
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.post(tmpResponseUrl + "continue=1").content, "html.parser")
    allButtons = soup.findAll('div', role='button')


allNews = soup.select('[data-params]')
for i in allNews:
    text = i['data-params']
    number = text[text.find('[',7)+2: text.find(',', text.find('[',7))]
    print(i.text)
    inputs = input(f"{number}|Вопрос №{index} ")

    index += 1
    responseUrl += "entry." + number + f"={inputs}&"

answer = requests.post(responseUrl)
print(answer.status_code)
```